Quantifying the distance between two discrete fuzzy sets
I am looking to use fuzzy sets to represent several collections of data points. Then, given a crisp set, I'd like to determine which collection the crisp set is most similar to.
Each collection is made up of some number of crisp sets. And I was thinking of constructing a fuzzy set representing the collection like so:
Let the universe be: a,b,c,d,e,f,g
Let A be a collection of the following sets:
A = [
[a,b,c],
[a,b,d],
[a,e,d]
]
Let B be a collection of the following sets:
B = [
[a,c,e],
[a,c,f],
[a,b,g]
]
The fuzzy set representing A would then be: {(a,1.0), (b,0.66), (c,0.33), (d,0.66), (e, 0.33), (f,0.0), (g,0.0)}
The fuzzy set representing B would then be: {(a,1.0), (b,0.33), (c,0.66), (d,0.0), (e,0.33), (f,0.33), (g,0.33)}
Suppose we now have a crisp set C = [a,b,c]. I'd like to determine how close C is to fuzzy sets A and B to infer which collection C is most likely to belong to.
I've been reviewing some materials on computing distances between fuzzy sets. Specifically I have reviewed lectures 17-19 from this video series:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luloamOA_c4
In the videos it is shown how the distance between two fuzzy sets is expressed as a fuzzy set in itself. I feel comfortable with how one might compute this distance fuzzy set, but I am unclear on how I can compare these resulting distance sets.
My understanding is that I could compute two fuzzy sets corresponding to the distance(A,C), and distance(B,C) respectively.
But how can I then tell whether C is 'closer' to A or B?
Would it make sense to use the scalar cardinality of distance(A,C) and distance(B,C)? So if the scalar cardinality of distance(A,C) is smaller than that of distance(B,C) I can say that C is closer to A?
Or am I horribly misunderstanding the intuition behind fuzzy sets, their distances, and their similarities, and thus misusing these constructs?
